# Vuforia AR rotate playing video on flat surface towards user

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Within Vuforia AR I am triggering a playing video on a flat table surface from a marker.

I would like rotate the video on the table so that it is the correct way up for people to watch from and angle that they approach the target.

I am assuming that I need to rotate the video player around the Y axis based on the AR camera.

I have tried pointing the video at the camera but getting some really strange results.  That when I realised i just want to keep the video player flat on the surface.

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
    transform.rotation = rotation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I just needed to rotate the object around the y Axix so it stayed flat on the table.  I did initially think it wasn't working as was behaving strange when running theunity but was perfect when testing on a device.

```
public Transform target;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 newRotation = new Vector3(0, target.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    this.transform.eulerAngles = newRotation;
}
```